# Ethereum: Why do call functions require gas?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

Why do call functions have gas?

```
contract MyContract {
  string public dapp_name = "my app";
  .....
```

```
$ truffle console --network kovan
$ c = await MyContract.deployed()
$ c.dapp_name()
// echos "my app"
$ c.dapp_name.estimateGas()
// echos 24403
```

Why does `estimateGas` for `dapp_name` return `24403 Gas`?

Isn't the `dapp_name` function a **call** function (meaning it's read only) and costs no gas?

Answer (score 1):

The gas is still needed to terminate any function.

If there is an infinite loop in a smart contract function calling it would hang the Ethereum API node. Eventually, all gas is burned and the loop forcefully terminates.

This is the measure against so-called "Turing completeness". All programs must terminate.

Comment: I totally get that for functions that write state. But aren't functions that only read state gas less?

Comment: The gas is never credited to a miner or node, but it is still needed as an internal unit of account to terminate the transaction. So gas is just an internal unit of account to ensure functions cannot run indefinitely.